# AS3 select childeren in node

Tags: xml, actionscript-3

The current code is selecting all the items in `<slideshow>` using `var itemsNode : XMLList = (xmlObject.children());`

but i added an extra node to the xml called sunday around a couple of items. what should i change about `var itemsNode : XMLList = (xmlObject.children());` to select all the items inside the node sunday, so i get the same result with `var itemsNode : XMLList = (xmlObject.children());` and without the sunday node?

```
<slideshow width = "560" height = "373" 
        startWith = "1"
        backgroundColor = "0xB9A0BD" 
        backgroundTransparency = "0"
        randomSlideshow = "true"
        loop = "true">

    <sunday>
        <item>
            <path>content/images/image1.jpg</path>
            <target>_blank</target>

            <transitionTime>1</transitionTime>
            <slideShowTime>3</slideShowTime>
        </item>

        <item>
            <path>content/images/image2.jpg</path>
            <target>_blank</target>

            <transitionTime>1</transitionTime>
            <slideShowTime>3</slideShowTime>
        </item>
    </sunday>

</slideshow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
var items:XMLList = xmlObject.sunday.item;
```

Comment: correct, there was something wrong with the for loop :s. little of topic how to get the name of the day in AC3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the awesome [E4X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECMAScript_for_XML) syntax to get all descendants (at any depth) of `xmlObject` named `item`:

```
var itemNodes : XMLList = xmlObject..item;
```

If you just want to skip one level (i.e. `sunday`) before selecting items, you can do:

```
var itemNodes : XMLList = xmlObject.*.item;
```